# Generic class whose field with the generic type migth be null

Tags: java, generics

I need to create a class that I'm planning to return an instance of at the end of each operation. Here's the class with its fields:

```
public class OperationResult<T> {
   private OperationStatus status;
   private String message;
   private T data;

    public OperationResult(OperationStatus status, T data, String message) {
       this.status = status;
       this.data = data;
       this.message = message;
    }

    public OperationResult(OperationStatus status, String message) {
       this.status = status;
       this.message = message;
   }
}
```

As you can see, there're 2 constructors: One that expects T data and the one that doesn't. That's because some operations provide some details along with the status and the message, while others don't. Now, take a look at the following method that might return the instance of OperationResult with different types:

```
 OperationResult getCustomerCurrentBalance(int customerId){
     if(a<0){
        return new OperationResult(OperationStatus.FAIL,"Invalid customer id passed");//No data
     }
     
     Customer customer = getCustomerById(customerId);
     if(!customer.isActive()){
        return new OperationResult(OperationStatus.FAIL,customer,"Customer is not active");//OperationResult<Customer> is returned
     }

     BigDecimal balance = getCustomerBalance(customerId);
     return new OperationResult(OperationStatus.SUCCESS,balance,null);//OperationResult<BigDecimal> is returned
 }
```

As you can see, I can't set the return type of the method to OperationResult class that expects a specific type as different versions might actually be returned. If I leave it like this, the compiler won't complain, but on the other hand, raw use of a parameterized class is not good. That being said, do you have any idea regarding this? Maybe the way I'm trying to use generics in this particular requirement is not right?

Comment: In my opinion, it is a very weird design. Exceptional behaviour should be handled with exceptions. A "getAccountBalance" method should return some number. If it returns a customer, car, or elephant, then there is something weird going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find a better solution, I will advice you to give a try with inheritance.

- class OperationResult : super class
- class SpecificOperationResult: generic class

```
class OperationResult {
    protected OperationStatus status;
    protected String message;

    public OperationResult(OperationStatus status, String message) {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
    }
}

class SpecificOperationResult<T> extends OperationResult {
    private T data;

    public SpecificOperationResult(OperationStatus status, T data, String message) {
        super(status, message);
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```